# add an existing .js file to an angularjs 2 application

Tags: angular

At my company we have a standard header for all websites which consists of a .js file and some .css to display it with the corporate style.

We have successfully used this in an AngularJS1 application by adding the following to the index.html

```
<script src="header/js/header.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header/css/header.light.min.css">
```

We are now in the process of converting our site to AngularJS2 and I have added both these lines to the index.html file of the new AngularJS2 application.

The header displays correctly but when I run NPM start it says it can't find the .js file.

I have tried all the answers I can find but I can't get it to work.

Please could someone put me out of my misery

Thank you very much